# Installation Problem: Magento 1.9 Blank Page

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

While trying to install Magento 1.9 on my CentOS/APACHE server, when I open the `install.php` file in the browser, getting a blank page.

I would want someone to help me through this please, stuck on it since hours now, and am not able to find a solution to that.

For the reference, here is the link: <strike>http://www.bluetopink.com/magento/install.php</strike>

Comment: looks like permission issue on your installation files

Comment: @amit_game Please could you help me through fixing the permission issues?, I've been getting bugged and irritated with this issue. I would be really glad on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

you can fix this with give the directories and files the right permission

you can use this:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chown APACHE_USER:APACHE_GROUP -R *
```

you can find the name of apache user and group in `/etc/passwd`

if the problem still doesn't solve,you can use [Magento Downloader](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download) that can helps you to see what should you install or do to run magento :)

Comment: This is the new error encountered now. Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Also, after using the downloader, the same thing happens. Please check this page: http://bluetopink.com/downloader.php?action=downloader.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is working: You can turn on ERROR REPORTING, and read the ERROR MESSAGE.

You can put this code in your `index.php` on a development/test installation.

```
$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
    register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
    function fatal_handler() {
        if($error = error_get_last()) {
        echo("<hr/ ><pre>");
        print_r($error);
        echo '<br/><br/>'.PHP_EOL;
        debug_print_backtrace();
        echo '<br/><br/></pre>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
}
```

And then post the exception here in this thread.

**But your server isn't working !**

http://www.bluetopink.com/magento/LICENSE.txt <== Did you remove this file ?

So, maybe add this the top of your `index.php`:

```
<?php die('Yes, it works.. \o/   Awesome !');
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me but I've made the changes you told me to, and nothing happens. Rather my server now gives me an internal 500 server error. **Please could you help me through**?

Comment: Maybe it's better not to do this 'online' ! Go to your root directory of your web-server, like 'public_html' and create a page called: 'info.php' also rename/remove .htaccess file. Inside file write: <?php phpinfo(); then browse:  http://www.bluetopink.com/info.php   (You have to see all your settings) But this is off-topic, your on Magento.stackexchange Maybe ask this question on a other thread. Good luck ! (Ps: Contact your administrator)

Comment: Hey it works !, Your getting a `downloader` ! (Goto index.php and remove downloader and just upload your files with ftp, when you goto your root you will see your installer !) Ps: Make shure your using 755 when copying your files. So look at your rights....(with FileZilla or something)

Comment: Mate, here is the file: http://www.bluetopink.com/magento/info.php

Comment: I've been trying the same thing, but what is happening is, its giving me an internal server error 500. www.bluetopink.com/magento, as well as root.

Answer (score 0):

Me again !

**I saw your downloader !** (Webserver is working)

This is how it works: (look in index.php)

```
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {  // <== You don't have 'app/Mage.php'
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}
```

Your base url = http://www.bluetopink.com/ and not http://www.bluetopink.com/magento/

So, don't worry, it's not hard to install Magento 1.9.2

First you want to do is DOWNLOAD Magento 1.9.2 CE your selfs. 
Goto: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download en download Magento + 'Sample Data'

Then download a good FTP client, like Filezilla.

First upload all files. Magento first, Sample data next (without data.sql) file. Make shure you right are correct. First start with 755 and make it better when it all works. (Right click on file and you will see a menu !)

Then goto something like: http://www.bluetopink.com/phpmyadmin to access your Database. Import the data.sql file from the sample database.

After that, browse: http://www.bluetopink.com/ and you will see your installer. (So you will SKIP downloading and just start with installing)

If installing goes wrong.... goto: /app/etc/ and remove local.xml, this will trigger the installer. So, no Mage.php = downloader and no local.xml = installer.

If you have questions, mail: lucifer.iix@ (The mail service from google :-)

Comment: Mailed you mate. **Been trying the same**. Awaiting your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that config.xml file exist on app/etc/ folder

Answer (score -1):

Download these file, unzip and put in your root folder of Magento installation and check Magento requirement and solve permission issues, respectively

http://www.magentocommerce.com/_media/magento-check.zip

for Permission issue paste below code, and create file `magento-cleanup.php`:

```
<?php

## Function to set file permissions to 0644 and folder permissions to 0755

function AllDirChmod( $dir = "./", $dirModes = 0755, $fileModes = 0644 ){
   $d = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir );
   foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $d, 1 ) as $path ){
      if( $path->isDir() ) chmod( $path, $dirModes );
      else if( is_file( $path ) ) chmod( $path, $fileModes );
  }
}

## Function to clean out the contents of specified directory

function cleandir($dir) {

    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_file($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                if (unlink($dir.'/'.$file)) { }
                else { echo $dir . '/' . $file . ' (file) NOT deleted!
'; }
            }
            else if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                cleandir($dir.'/'.$file);
                if (rmdir($dir.'/'.$file)) { }
                else { echo $dir . '/' . $file . ' (directory) NOT deleted!
'; }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

}

function isDirEmpty($dir){
     return (($files = @scandir($dir)) && count($files) ";
$start = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
echo "
*************** SETTING PERMISSIONS ***************
";
echo "Setting all folder permissions to 755
";
echo "Setting all file permissions to 644
";
AllDirChmod( "." );
echo "Setting pear permissions to 550
";
chmod("pear", 550);

echo "
****************** CLEARING CACHE ******************
";

if (file_exists("var/cache")) {
    echo "Clearing var/cache
";
    cleandir("var/cache");
}

if (file_exists("var/session")) {
    echo "Clearing var/session
";
    cleandir("var/session");
}

if (file_exists("var/minifycache")) {
    echo "Clearing var/minifycache
";
    cleandir("var/minifycache");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/cache")) {
    echo "Clearing downloader/pearlib/cache
";
    cleandir("downloader/pearlib/cache");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/download")) {
    echo "Clearing downloader/pearlib/download
";
    cleandir("downloader/pearlib/download");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/pear.ini")) {
    echo "Removing downloader/pearlib/pear.ini
";
    unlink ("downloader/pearlib/pear.ini");
}

echo "
************** CHECKING FOR EXTENSIONS ***********
";
If (!isDirEmpty("app/code/local/")) { 
    echo "-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/local folder
";
}
If (!isDirEmpty("app/code/community/")) { 
    echo "-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/community folder
";
}
$end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
echo "
------------------- CLEANUP COMPLETED in:". sprintf("%.4f", ($end-$start))." seconds ------------------
";
?>
```

Comment: What is this and why are you asking people to download and install it? If this is an official resource please add the official links.

Comment: @mbalparda, its not an official site, just want to solve the issue, and thanks for your suggestion, I will remember for next in future.

Comment: Please post a proper answer. This is entirely inappropriate.